# Why is my relay using nowhere near the bandwidth that's available to it?

Tags: relays, bandwidth, speed

I have 1.25 MBps (10 Mbps) of usable bandwidth in both directions. Yet my relay constantly hovers around 100 KBps of advertised bandwidth. It's currently been up for 6 days and 4 hours (after a long hibernation. It previously ran for longer with short breaks, but with identical speed issues). It's hosted on a computer with a i5, so I'm certain it's not a CPU bottleneck. I also have Vidalia's bandwidth set at 1000 KBps bandwidth with 1250 KBps peak.

Is there anything I can do to make my relay more fully utilize the available bandwidth? Or should I give up and run a bridge instead?

The node's fingerprint is 98EF2C42194EFE540D30AD10C5071B2ED4BBA4C8 .

Cheers - Some Tor Dude.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that a firewall is giving you some troubles.
It could also be that you're using the wrong config file (I only mention this because it happened to me once).

Are you running an exit node or just a regular relay?
If you're running a regular relay then a slow increase in bandwidth could just be part of the [relay's natural lifecycle](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay).
If you're running an exit relay then [this is more unusual](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4289/exit-node-maturity).